# Отличие файлов SharedPreferences от обычных файлов

Tags: android, файловая-система, android-shared-preferences

Определение SharedPreferences из документации:

> Объект SharedPreferences указывает на файл, содержащий пары
>   "ключ-значение", и предоставляет простые методы для чтения и записи.
>   Управление каждым файлом SharedPreferences осуществляется с помощью
>   инфраструктуры и может быть частным или общим.

А чем отличаются файлы, используемые SharedPreferences, от обычных файлов в файловой системе Android? Одно из отличий, как написано в той же документации, если я правильно понимаю, состоит в строго определённой структуре файла (набор пар "ключ-значение"). А есть ли ещё отличия? Например, эти файлы можно прочитать только программно (т.е. можно прочитать только из приложения/приложений, которые обращаются к этим SharedPreferences, а открыть из файловой системы их нельзя) или же это неверно?

Comment: в остальном это обычный XML-файл, который находится где то в каталоге приложения (data/data/<pacage_name>/..). Вы можете работать с ним, как с обычным файлом, если вам это зачем то понадобилось

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Файлы SharedPreferences это обычные файлы с расширением .xml которые располагаются в подкаталоге конкретного приложения. При этом права доступа к файлу прописываются такие же как и всем остальным, которые принадлежат данному приложению. Соответственно получить доступ к нему можно не только программно, но и из файловой системы. Другим программам на устройстве получить доступ к данному файлу не удастся,так как они не имеют соответствующих прав, за исключением тех программ которые имеют права root или же подписаны тем же сертификатом, что и программа которой принадлежит SharedPreferences